# How to breach Angularjs using $watch?

Tags: angularjs, security

In angular js security documentation it is written using $watch to watch the value of user generated content is unsafe:

> There are a number of ways that templates and expressions can be controlled:...
>
> Passing an expression generated from user-provided content in calls to the following methods on a scope:
> ...
>
> $watch(userContent, ...)

What is the meaning of userContent here? If I watch ngModel value of user input field, is this a userContent? Is the form in the fiddle unsafe?

Comment: Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/un55cprk/

Answer (score 3):

**`$watch` expression is restricted form of `eval`**, where an expression is parsed by AngularJS expression parser and evaluated against current scope.

Although AngularJS expression parser has security measures against evaluating arbitrary JS code with real `eval`, security hazards may still exist, and known vulnerabilities can be potentially exploited in older framework versions.

This means that `$on.constructor('alert(1)')()` expression cannot be evaluated and won't create a security threat in any up-to-date AngularJS version. But considering that `$window` service was exposed to scope (which is a common practice for ES6 controllers), `$window.alert(1)` expression can be evaluated.

This **cannot** pose a security threat:

```
$scope.$watch('myValue', function () {
    console.log($scope.myValue);
});
```

This **can** pose a security threat:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.myValue, function () {
    console.log($scope.myValue);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, if I bind the `myVar` to a text input field and user enters some javascript it causes problem?

Comment: It's safe, as long as you do `$watch('myVar', ...)` and not `$watch($scope.myVar, ...)` (which wouldn't have desirable effect any way).

Comment: we have lots of `$watch($scope.myVar, ...)` throughout our application what should we to now?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Are you sure that you supply `$scope.myVar` scope property and not static value as the first arg? I cannot think of a good reason for that. Because again, this is a form of eval. If this is so and you're unsure how it should be fixed, consider asking a new question that explains your case in details and contains http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 0):

With $watch you can keep an eye on any  ng-model. For example you have 1 graph and above that you have a dropdown of year to date , month to date,quarter to date.
Now say, name of the dropdown model is dateChange 
Now you can keep a watch on dateChange so so whenever there is an update in the dateChange, $watch function will come to know and you can then update the data of the graph with respect to the selection

Comment: I know what the `$watch` is used for! I want to know what is the use case of bad usage of `$watch` which open your application to XSS attacks.