# In Angular 1.x When "watching" in a directive; why does watching a function that returns a variable act different than just watching the variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, closures

The easiest way to explain this question is with some sample code so here is a very simple directive written in ES6 syntax:

```
export default class IsFoo {

  constructor() {
    // Set the directive properties
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.require = 'ngModel';
  }

  link(scope, element, attributes, controller) {

    let foo = scope.$eval(attributes.foo);

    controller.$validators.isFooBar = (modelValue) => {

      // make sure we have the most recent value foo
      foo = attributes.foo;

        return foo === 'bar';
      };

      scope.$watch(() => {return attributes.foo;}, () => controller.$validate());
  }

  static directiveFactory() {
    IsFoo.instance = new IsFoo();
    return IsFoo.instance;
  }

}

IsFoo.directiveName = 'isFooBar';
```

That is a rough version of my directive with all the actual important validation removed.. it's pretty simple.

If I change the watch line to be:

```
scope.$watch(attributes.foo), ()=>controller.$validate());
```

It doesn't work.  Why?  Why does the function returning the `attributes.foo` work?

What is the difference that causes the end result to be different?

Also, disclaimer, I'm intentionally not using scope isolation because the directive is being used on an element that has another directive that uses scope isolation.. so they collide and you get an error `Multiple directives asking for new/isolated scope on: xxx`.

My rough guess is that it is related to how closures behave in javascript but I can't wrap my head around how the two behaving differently.

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: `scope.$watch(attributes.foo...` is a mistake and potential security issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362623/how-to-breach-angularjs-using-watch

Comment: thanks @estus that makes sense.  I'm glad I asked this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface for `scope.$watch` is according to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) the following:

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
```

With `watchExpression` being either a `string` or a `function`. If it is a `string`, it is interpreted as a path within your `scope` object. Assuming `attributes.foo` is `"test.something"`, it will watch `scope.test.something` - if it exists.

If you want to watch for changes of the value of `attributes.foo`, you have to use the `function`, or attach `attributes.foo` to your scope and passing `"attributes.foo"` as `watchExpression`.